# Is it worth buffing my partner (dual wield fighter) via spells?

Tags: two-worlds-2

Is it worth buffing my partners strength via spells?

It's kind of tedious to target her with my enchant while she runs around in her killing spree. I had the idea of switching to a homing missile + enchant buff to simplify the aiming but I didn't have the time to test that ingame. Adding ricochets would buff my summons as well, wouldn't it?